# English/German one word for "in progress"

Tags: translation, word-choice, synonym

I'm looking for an English/German word for the term "in progress" (or "in process"). I search for this term in relation to the life cycle of a project, which (in my specific case) are:

- open
- accepted
- in progress
- closed
- rejected

... which would be in German:

- offen
- angenommen
- in Umsetzung
- umgesetzt (or abgeschlossen)
- abgelehnt

And in strikes my understanding of aesthetic that "in progress" and "in Umsetzung" is a two worder. Do you have anything else to offer? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't point it out well enough. I'm not looking for a "better" word for "in progress" or "in Umsetzung" (albeit I appreaciate your thoughts on that!), I was simply forced to find a one worder in both languages as an answer to the "function follows form" paradigma. Anyway: Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Autoren der Frage können diese umformulieren - das gehört nicht in einen Kommentar. Die Frage soll ohne Lesen der Kommentare verständlich sein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- open - eröffnet
- accepted - angenommen
- active - aktiv
- closed - abgeschlossen/beendet
- rejected - abgelehnt

Personally I still prefer the two word phrase "*in progress - In Bearbeitung*" in this context.

Comment: Thanks for "active/aktiv". Actually something I was looking for, no matter if appropriate for project life cycle terms.

Comment: I chose to accept this answer as it is the first which properly answers my question (a one worder in both languages). Thanks!

Comment: Projektmitarbeiter sind aktiv - aber nicht das Projekt selbst.

Answer (score 8):

You would not say *in Umsetzung* in German. Correct would be *wird umgesetzt*, for your case I would use the short term *in Arbeit* or semantically better, but longer *in Bearbeitung*.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you should note that **läuft** is a commonly used slang word but definitely nothing to use at work.

Comment: Interesting, but with no attention to the question ;-)

Comment: `in Umsetzung` wird zumindest im innerbetrieblichem Sprachgebrauch durchaus angewandt. Ich würde nicht sagen, dass es inkorrekt ist - lediglich nicht alltäglich.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer

> in Bearbeitung

instead of `in Umsetzung`.

In my opinion is open/offen not a good term or the state is unclear.
`offen` is a good translation for `open`, but i think it is a umbrella term like `active` for

- new
- accepted / assigned
- in progress

The Project Ticket System "Trac" has a `new` state.
see [German translation from the Trac Ticket System](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TranslationDe/TracTickets)

They also translated `closed` with `abgeschlossen`.

Comment: I cannot use "new/neu" as this indicates something else in my project. Thanks for the hint with "in Bearbeitung".

Answer (score 2):

Messageboxes with a progress bar in computer programs usually have `Bearbeitung läuft` as translation to `in progress`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's see. I probably wouldn't use "offen" for open. If we're talking about the life-cycle of a project, perhaps "aktuell" or "aktiv" might work? Likewise, "abgeschlossen" is a much better choice than geschlossen or umgesetzt, in my opinion.

As to "in progress": what about "in Arbeit"?

Comment: I don't think that "aktiv/aktuell" is a good choice for open topics because it's indicating that something is/will happen(ing). You can find several open bugs in a bugtracker which have not been active for a long time. So I suggest to perhaps use "ungeprüft" or "Auf Entscheidung wartend". However the later isn't concise enough for a life-cycle.

Comment: Everything depends on context, obviously. For a bug-tracker "ungelöst" or similar might be an option, but I would have thought you needed different statuses there anyway.

Comment: I like "aktuell" or "aktiv" in order to answer my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This pair is what I've seen quite often:

> in progress: *im Prozess*

Comment: "Im Prozess" sounds rather like trial.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps better as a trivialism rather than for the name of a project phase...

underway: *unterwegs*

Comment: My understanding is that this means more like, "on the way" but it still makes sense, I think.

Comment: Also interesting, especially if lifecycle terms refer to logistic industrie. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A one-word synonym for "In progress" is "Pending", in English. In German, Google translate tells me the word is "anstehend".

Comment: `anstehend` means that something is enqueued or scheduled *to be* processed in the near future. Another translation is upcoming.

Answer (score 0):

How about "fortschreitend" and "ongoing"?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, not in this context.